# CHEF Server--Error: Network Error: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I'm trying to update a Chef server that is hosted on a AWS EC2 instance. This is what happens when I'm trying to connect to the server:

```
$ knife ssl check
Error: Network Error: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not  
known
```

I can only think of issues w/ the knife configuration. However, all knife functions work within the AWS EC2 instance, while not on my local machine (Macbook+iTerm).

**knife.rb on EC2**

```
log_level              :info
log_location           STDOUT
node_name              'jdoe'
client_key             '/home/ec2-user/.chef/jdoe.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://ip-xx-x-x-xxx.ec2.internal:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/home/ec2-user/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
```

**knife.rb on local machine**

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'jdoe'
client_key               '/Users/.../.chef/jdoe.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/Users/.../.chef/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://ip-xx-x-x-xxx.ec2.internal:443'       
syntax_check_cache_path  '/Users/yoonsulee/.chef/syntax_check_cache'

# Amazon AWS
knife[:aws_access_key_id]='A...........Q'     # actual access key
knife[:aws_secret_access_key]='Q.............................g'      # actual secret access eky
knife[:aws_ssh_key_id]='xyz-abcd'        # general key name used for AWS access
```

My AWS security group and ACL are all fine. And I was somehow able to download 'trusted_certs' from:

```
$ knife ssl fetch
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to do the following from my Chef repo directory:

```
$ berks upload <new_cookbook> --force
$ knife role from file ../../roles/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is due to you using the internal DNS name of your EC2 instance. Unless you are VPN'd in to your AWS VPC this will not resolve.
You should change your workstation's knife.rb to use the Public DNS name if it exists. If you do not wish to create a public endpoint for your instance, you will need to VPN to your VPC to have internal endpoints resolvable.

Comment: I did use a Public DNS in the knife.rb, but the error message is saying that the certificate (downloaded in the ~/.chef/trusted_certs) does not match the Chef-server certificate in the AWS instance (var/opt/opscode/../nginx/ca/SERVER_HOSTNAME.crt). FYI, the certificate I have resonates w/ the above Internal/Private DNS.

Comment: chef server must have a resolvable host name.
edit /etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb - change the first line:
server_name = "instance-public-dns-record-here"
save and then run:
"sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure"
Clear your local trusted_certs folder and re-run
knife ssl check
knife ssl fetch

Comment: I changed the _chef-server.rb_ syntax in the AWS instance but could not run the "sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure" command:  

    'ERROR: Permission denied - /opt/chef-   server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-client-running.pid'

'FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)'

Is there a way to read-in the repo on my local machine from the AWS instance to add roles, cookbook, etc?

Comment: can you re-run sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure - are you getting the same response? might be just a stale pid.

Comment: I changed the 'api_fqdn' to the public DNS url that matches the local knife.rb. 'knife ssl check' was verified so it's promising. I was able to upload new roles from my repo directory using 'knife role from file ../../roles*' but when trying to do 'berks upload <new_cookbook_name> --force' I get a "There was an error connecting to the Chef Server" error. Also, when trying to do 'knife ec2 server create ...' I was able to launch a new instance, but don't seem like all the recipes were implemented. Should I just go back to the original chef-server.rb which did work a while ago?